# executing a testng java test with python for junit results

Tags: java, python-2.7, unit-testing, junit, testng

Hi and thanks in advance,

I have several scripts in python(2.7+) which produce junit test results. Currently I am trying to leverage some java testng code. I was wondering if there is a way to use python to execute java testng code while including it in a junit test suite. I am aware that testng produces a junit reports folder.

- Note for the python junit scripts, I am using [xmlrunner](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmlrunner/1.7.7) to produces the results.

Answer (score 0):

A solution may be to call a command prompt from your python code which calls the prompts to execute the java environment. To call TestNG or JUnit for example, you just have to call the specific jar file from the lib.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen("java...", shell=True, ...)
```

You can catch the returncode to check if the tests where executed correctly.